# Android JARSIGNER GUI tool?

Tags: android, jarsigner

Newbie question.

After I have written the Android App (easy part) I need to sign it and upload it (seems the hard part)

Is there an Open Source app or tool that I can use to do this so that I don't have to write command shell scripts. JARSIGNER looks overly complex.

I'm looking for a dead simple Sign-And-Package up tool.

I am using Eclipse with the Android plug in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using eclipse so just right-click on your project -> choose export - choose android and the follow the steps of the export wizard

Comment: OMG, that is too easy. I am coming from the iPhone world and it's a more complicated there....

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on project and choosing "Android Tools->Export Signed Application Package" is an alternate way of doing what RoflcoptrException suggests

Answer (score 1):

I've played a bit with [keystore-explorer](http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/), and it seems to fit the description of what you are looking for.  It describes itself as a "GUI replacement for the Java command-line utilities keytool, jarsigner and jadtool".